# Show all tags within a category?

Tags: php, functions, categories

How can I display a list of tags within a category page?

So my ***URL*** would look something like this.

```
https://example.com/category/tag
```

Then it would display only posts from that category, and that tag on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that would be to create a custom page template, and make a custom loop that would only display the posts in you specific category and tag.

For example:

```
global $wp_query; $args = array( 'category__and' => 'category', 'tag__in' => 'post_tag', //Enter tag id for this field (not tah name) 'posts_per_page' => -1); //Gets all posts $posts = get_posts($args); foreach ($posts as $post) :  endforeach;
```